# can't set the value in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

everything is correct but when i put : after value in this code

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'commands',
    description: 'command embed',
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const CommandsEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#FFC100')
        .setTitle('Commands')
        .setURL('http://bitly.com/98K8eH')
        .setDescription('Embed showing every command')
        .addFields()
            {name: 'Playlist', value: 'Playlist - only for stoners'}
    }
};
```

and when i try to run it it shows me that ':' is an unexpected token. Can I fix it somehow? I was doing it basing on this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7eZY-SBmf8&list=PLbbLC0BLaGjpyzN1rg-gK4dUqbn8eJQq4&index=5

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this inside `()` of `.addFields`:

```js
.addFields(
   {name: 'Playlist', value: 'Playlist - only for stoners'}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The objects should be inside the parenthesis, as described in the video

```
.addFields(
    {name: 'Rule 1', value: 'Be nice'},
    {name: 'Rule 2', value: 'follow twitch'},
    {name: 'Rule 3', value: 'no memes'}
)
```